# Validation loss diverging away from the training loss

Tags: neural-network, sentiment-analysis, transfer-learning

I used the XLNET for a sentiment classifier in determining whether a comment is positive or negative. I was able to get good results

[image]

But when I plotted the validation and training losses I saw this

[image]

I think this means that the model is overfitting? But I am not exactly sure. If there is any suggestions I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This kind of overfitting is typical when finetuning large LMs.

The usual approaches to "avoid" it are:

- Early stopping: select the checkpoint with the best validation loss.
- Random restarts: train multiple times from scratch, and select the model with the best validation performance.